# Springfox swagger is not working with an app that exposes only APIs (no UI of its own)

Tags: swagger

We have a spring app that:
1. Exposes APIs.
2. Does not have a UI (index.html) of its own.
3. Has security checks - every API call goes through authorization wherein, if the credentials are wrong, API will respond with Bad request(400) response.

I need to add swagger ui so that we are able to see the API documentation on the UI.
So, what should i do to be able to view the doucmentation UI generated by Swagger?
Note: 
1. i can add an index.html, but accessing that URL or the swagger url must not require any kind of authentication. 
2. Also, i want this to be available in our testing environment, there is no need for swagger ui to be available on Prod. 
this is for our internal customers only.

Adding some code snippets:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"x.x.x"})
public class XXApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultsUtil.setCommunity("1");
        SpringApplication.run(XX.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("XX").select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.ariba.collab.platform.restengine"))
                .paths(any()).build().apiInfo(new ApiInfo("Conversations",
                        "A set of operations on Chats", "1.0.0", "http://xxx.Policy.html",
                        new Contact("Team", null, "xxx@yyy.com"),null, null));
    }
}
```

THen in the Webconfig class i have added the Resource Handlers. Please guide me with the paths and locations. I'm not sure what these locations should be...

```
@Configuration
public class XWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private XRequestInterceptor interceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors (InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        /*registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");*/
    }

}
```

Then in the Controller class, i have added the API annotations.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ="/y")
@Api(value="y", description = "Operations on chats", tags=("chat"))
public class ConversationController {

    //get latest conversation
    @RequestMapping (value="/getChats", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ApiOperation(value="Get All Chats", notes="Get all existing chats", nickname = "getChatss")
    public CLResp getChats(@Valid @RequestBody CLDTO clDTO) throws ServiceException,ValidationException {
        CLResp resp = service.getChatss(clDTO);
        if(resp.getRespObjs() != null) {
            //do something
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

after doing all this, when i compile and run the app, i'm getting an error like this:
HTTP Status: 401
Basic

also, we have some security classes which do not allow for accessing these APIs directly. The authentication is Basic and must be valid for the API call to go through. From Postman, if i want to make an API call, i need to provide the Basic authentication credentials correctly. How do i fix this? Please guide me with this as this is the 1st time...

this is the code written for Security config:

```
http
.sessionManagement()
.and()
.exceptionHandling()
.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
.and()
.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
.authorizeRequests()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.addFilterAfter(authenticationFilter, 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http
        .csrf().disable();
```

how do i remove the authentication for Swagger UI html alone?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Are you stuck with something while trying? Maybe then we can chime in to help out.

Comment: If you are just looking for a starting point, maybe this helps http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: yes, i have started. i have added the maven dependencies, the annotations and written an implementaiton for `code` public Docket api(){ ... }  `code` . currently it is giving me a 400 bad request error.

Comment: Some snippets of  relevant code might help us to figure out the issue.